# Are Vampires disguised as Vigilants of Stendarr still called "Vigilant(s) of Stendarr" when fought?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Talking about what UESP calls [World_Interactions#Vampire_Masquerade](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:World_Interactions#Vampire_Masquerade).

Because I saw a clip of a "Vigilant of Stendarr" attacking a player out of nowhere, and was wondering why that happened, thinking it might be vampires.

Comment: Was the player wearing daedric gear or a stage 4 vampire?  Also being witnessed transforming to/from Werewolf/Vampire Lord will mark someone as an enemy of the Vigilants.

Comment: @tjd - Nope, level 2 basic Nord without any Bound gear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.** Once the Vigilants of Stendarr impersonators have been aggroed, both the subtitles and the health bar text will identify them as vampires.

In this example, notice that once the player aggroed what was identified as a “Vigilant of Stendarr” in the dialogue UI, the subtitles and the health bar text then immediately identified it and its companions as “Vampire Fledgeling” or “Vampire”:

[image: animated GIF described above]

YouTube videos showing the above in action: [[1]](https://youtu.be/n6I4FeIbeqw?t=17) [[2]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvDtJGnmVQk) [[3]](https://youtu.be/p_rbL1p-XBQ?t=4).

> I saw a clip of a "Vigilant of Stendarr" attacking a player out of nowhere, and was wondering why that happened, thinking it might be vampires.

Those are probably actual Vigilants of Stendarr, if they’re still identified as such even after aggroing them.